# Creating a file in Docker build

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell, dockerfile

I am building an image that installs dependencies, clones a git repository, setups python environment, updates config files and creates systemctl service. Everything works find except a script (**start.sh**) I try to create at the end of the process. It seems to be present during the **docker build** step but once I run the image, it disappears.

```sh
# Dockerfile 
RUN echo "#!/bin/bash" > start.sh
RUN echo "systemctl start jenkins" >> start.sh
RUN echo "systemctl start runserver" >> start.sh
RUN cat start.sh
RUN chmod +x start.sh
```

My docker build terminal output

```
Step 28/32 : RUN echo "#!/bin/bash" > start.sh
 ---> Running in 4a3f91a67b90
Removing intermediate container 4a3f91a67b90
 ---> 7fc47c36f4b8
Step 29/32 : RUN echo "systemctl start jenkins" >> start.sh
 ---> Running in 6807840fab7e
Removing intermediate container 6807840fab7e
 ---> d945ba395f9d
Step 30/32 : RUN echo "systemctl start runserver" >> start.sh
 ---> Running in 205c38c6e9e3
Removing intermediate container 205c38c6e9e3
 ---> 5684fd6346b9
Step 31/32 : RUN cat start.sh
 ---> Running in ce3326beb99c
#!/bin/bash
systemctl start jenkins
systemctl start runserver
Removing intermediate container ce3326beb99c
 ---> efd96d67c6c3
Step 32/32 : RUN chmod +x start.sh
 ---> Running in fffd5de0f924
```

I have tried to set absolute path to define the target file:

```sh
# Dockerfile 
RUN echo "#!/bin/bash" > /home/ubuntu/start.sh
...
```

But it failed.

What could be wrong here?

**UPDATE**

To run the image:

```sh
docker run -tid \
            --name auto-server \
            --rm \
            --volume data:/home/ubuntu \
            --publish 8080:8080 \
            --publish 8000:8000 \
            --publish 50000:50000 \
            --cap-add=NET_ADMIN \
            --cap-add=NET_RAW \
            auto-server:1.0
```

To see that the shell disappears:

```sh
# container build
$ docker build -t auto-server:1.0 .
... 
Step 27/31 : RUN echo "#!/bin/bash" > /home/ubuntu/start.sh
 ---> Running in 2a022fcec2f4
Removing intermediate container 2a022fcec2f4
 ---> c9d1ff27d96f
Step 28/31 : RUN echo "systemctl start jenkins" >> /home/ubuntu/start.sh
 ---> Running in 3ed993cd03c7
Removing intermediate container 3ed993cd03c7
 ---> 0e8c4463c472
Step 29/31 : RUN echo "systemctl start runserver" >> /home/ubuntu/start.sh
 ---> Running in aa31dbce3716
Removing intermediate container aa31dbce3716
 ---> d48a1fd0580c
Step 30/31 : RUN cat /home/ubuntu/start.sh
 ---> Running in 23785ebdb620
#!/bin/bash                      <== File is present during build
systemctl start jenkins
systemctl start runserver
Removing intermediate container 23785ebdb620
 ---> 7499157cede3
Step 31/31 : RUN chmod +x /home/ubuntu/start.sh
 ---> Running in 43980bffe8cc
Removing intermediate container 43980bffe8cc
 ---> 2932ca0c3d29
Successfully built 2932ca0c3d29
Successfully tagged auto-server:1.0

$ docker run -tid \
            --name auto-server \
            --rm \
            --volume data:/home/ubuntu \
            --publish 8080:8080 \
            --publish 8000:8000 \
            --publish 50000:50000 \
            --cap-add=NET_ADMIN \
            --cap-add=NET_RAW \
            auto-server:1.0

$ docker exec -ti auto-server bash
root@a36c99271b8a:/home/ubuntu#
root@a36c99271b8a:/home/ubuntu# ls -la
total 1856
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root    4096 Oct  5 08:36 .
drwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    4096 Oct  6 05:56 ..
drwxr-xr-x. 8 root root    4096 Oct  5 09:21 auto
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 1885433 Oct  5 08:20 get-pip.py
```

When I use `CMD ["bash", "-c", "systemctl start jenkins"]` in my **Dockerfile**, Jenkins service is up when I run the image.

Comment: How are you running the image?  (Are you hiding the image contents with a volume?)  To a first approximation `systemctl` and similar commands just don't work in Docker, and it's usually a better practice to split this up into two separate containers than to try to run two separate services in one container.

Comment: `but once I run the image, it disappears.` Please show how you run the image and how do you know it dissapears?

Comment: Script should be there in the image itself. you verified that? Also RUN commands is used while building the image, for running the container process we must use CMD or ENTRYPOINT.

Comment: When you cat the script you're not redirecting to a file on the image. And the perms you're setting aren't in the file on the image. Wouldn't it be better to use the COPY cmd? You also need to set your entry point.

Comment: FYI each of those RUN commands creates a new image layer

Comment: @DavidMaze, please see update for the docker run command. It is ambiguous because systemctl works as I can acces to the Jenkins web UI when I run the image built with ```CMD ["bash", "-c", "systemctl start jenkins"]``` but when I check the Jenkins systemctl status, it says that it is not running. One service per container, is it easy to use jenkins to interact with another container with a web server?

Comment: @KamilCuk, please see **update** for more details

Comment: @VijayDaswani, yes I verified, my idea was to use CMD+ENTRYPOINT to lanch the script I try to make and the script would launch 2 services.

Comment: @Johnnie, I cat it from inside the container, to show that it has been done during the build step. Since its a quite simple script, I dont really want to have it on my repository to limit files in it, plus it is supposed to be used only by the container.

Comment: @jordanm, Should it have any impact on file creation and/ or update?

Comment: `--volume data:/home/ubuntu` .... So you __replace__ /home/ubuntu with some `data` volume, so everything inside will be lost. If you want some file to create within `data` volume, create it there.

Answer (score 0):

In your run command you mount local dir to `/home/ubuntu`

```
--volume data:/home/ubuntu \
```

Which mean anything inside `/home/ubuntu` will be replaced with the content of local `data` dir
You can write the script to diffrent path example `/opt/scripts/start.sh` 
Or you can create the script outside the `Dockerfile` in your `data` dir.